# How can I know whether camera supports a resolution or not in mac os x

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, objective-c++

I am working on a project and recently switch to objective c for a small period of time. I am facing some problem in mac osx while capturing video from camera using qtkit. I am currently using "setPixelBufferAttributes" to set different properties of captured video. The problem is :

1. If camera does not support 640 X 360 resolution and i am setting it using "setPixelBufferAttributes" then also video is captured and internally converted to 640 X 360 Which I dont need. So I don't want automatic conversion of resolutions.
2. I want all supported resolutions supported by camera hardware directly.

Please guide me if any other API is also present...

Answer (score 0):

This code will enumerate the size of the video source from the `QTCaptureDevice`:

```
    [captureDevice.formatDescriptions enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(QTFormatDescription* formatDescription, NSUInteger idx, BOOL* stop) {
        NSDictionary* attributes = [formatDescription formatDescriptionAttributes];
        NSValue* videoEncodedPixelsSize = [attributes objectForKey:@"videoEncodedPixelsSize"];
        NSSize videoSize = [videoEncodedPixelsSize sizeValue];
        NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSize(videoSize));
    }];
```

Comment: This code is always giving only one single format (always 160 X 120)from camera and I need all supported format from device thanks, please help me if you find something for me...

Comment: What camera do you have? I get 640x480 from my MacBook Pro. What formats do you think your camera supports?

Comment: there are two cameras one supports 160 X 120 to 640 X 480 camera name is Microsoft lifecam VX-5000. Another is rocksoul full hd 1080p web camera it supports 640 X 360 and all other resolutions including 640 X 480 maintaining 4:3 and 16:9 both for video resolution. So I want to know what are all resolution a device supports..

Comment: I plugged in my MSFT camera and see the same problem. According to this thread QTKit only reports the minimum resolution... http://lists.apple.com/archives/quicktime-api/2011/Feb/msg00011.html

Comment: So you are saying that there is no way to get list of all supported resolutions.

Comment: I can't see any way of doing it

Comment: I also that's way question is put up.. :) may be someone is having another solution.